# Combine log files to one main log file in beats and send to logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat

Imagine that I have some log files like,

```
log_file_10_01_2020
log_file_11_01_2020
log_file_12_01_2020
log_file_13_01_2020
```

I want to combine all of them in beats and output to a one main log file and send that file to logstash.That will be the process of pipeline. (I know If i use * params in logstash its read all but I don't ask that.)

I mean combining logs in order in every pipeline.Like output of this pipeline will be main.log. And it has all the log files inside.

Is it possible to do that with beats? If yes how ?

Thanks for answering

Comment: I don't think this is possible, you need to combine the log yourself and configure filebeat to read only this log. And to guarantee the ordering you would need to configure your logstash to use only one worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the beat this is not possible, however, you can install logstash on the server to do this for you and then use the lumberjack output to send it to the beats input of your logstash (if this is on the same machine, use different pipelines)